# Mac - NSFileMangager setIcon:forFile:options: is not working for folders

Tags: objective-c, macos, icons, nsfilemanager

I'm using the `NSFileManager` for changing the icon of a file or folder via `setIcon:forFile:options:`. After that I call `noteFileSystemChanged:` that the new icon will be drawn. 
When I change the icon of a file it works every time. But when I change the icon of a folder it works only sometimes. 
Does anyone know the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

a folder is not really file as in it doesnt have a resource fork in the file

## till 10.9 you could

you could do it via icon services (non-deprecated carbon api)

or (shameless advertisement) via my NSWorkspace+IconBadging category from my DDUtils repo on github

https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDUtils/tree/master/DDUtils-OSX/ui/NSWorkspace%2BIconBadging%20%5Bosx%5D/NSWorkspace%2BIconBadging

---

nowawadays.. dont know but icon services must still work somehow since dropbox works ;)
but.. they are 32 bit

so with 64 bit API there might be no way

Comment: I already tried your category but since I updated to Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) it doesn't work anymore :/

Comment: oh .. diddnt try it in a long time.